# Problems with OpenCL (opencl.dll, AMD APP SDK, cl.h)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, opencl

I'm trying to work with OpenCL in Visual Studio and here's what's bothering me:

I have an ATI graphic card and so I downloaded AMD APP SDK, the latest version 3.1, and wanted to start developing on some example but got stuck because there was no "cl.h" nor CL folder for that matter in that SDK. I found that very strange, since in all the examples Ive seen the include was: #include . Then I downloaded an older version, I think its 2.7., and there was CL folder with cl.h file as well. I then also made sure all the library dependencies and include directories are set in the project properties and when i tried to run an existing OpenCL project there were no errors reported. However, when the program started it crashed because it was saying that "OpenCL.dll is missing". I looked in the SDK folder for the file and it wasnt there. I then downloaded opencl.dll from internet and copied it into debug folder and tried to start the program again but it crashed again with a message "Opencl.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.".

Im really lost here and would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Did you add opencl.lib located in C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.1\lib\x86_64 into linker properties of your project? If you have this folder linked to your project you don't really need to have opencl.dll.

Comment: Yes I did and the console gives me this error. Program compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't download "Opencl.dll" explicitly, it should come as part of your [drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) installation. Header files & Lib files can be part of SDK, but run-time files like "Opencl.dll" are not necessarily be part of SDK. Crash can be observed if there is no compatibility between the SDK files (Headers and libraries that you use for your application) and Run-time files (Opencl.dll).

So, make sure to update drivers corresponding to the SDK version that you use.

Also, the opencl.dll generally get placed in "C:\Windows\System32" & "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" when you install the drivers. Generally, this is the one that gets used during run-time

Comment: Amd auto detect cant find a driver for my card. Great :D

Comment: That's very unlikely, did you try manually choosing the drivers then? Do you know the card name/number?